# Asp.Net Core 2.2 Identity Authentication

Tags: c#, authentication, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity

I am having a weird situation in my web app whereby I can successfully sign in but not authenticated. I have checked the property: User.Identity.IsAuthenticated property and its value is false. I am using the default Account controller

```
var result = await _signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(model.Email, model.Password, model.RememberMe, lockoutOnFailure: true);
```

I put a break break-point and the value of result is Success but User.Identity.IsAuthenticated is false.

Below is my code for the ConfigureServices method in Startup class:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddDbContext<SchoolIdentityContext>(options =>
            options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("IdentityConnection")));

        services.AddIdentity<User, IdentityRole>()
            .AddEntityFrameworkStores<SchoolIdentityContext>()
            .AddDefaultTokenProviders();

        services.ConfigureApplicationCookie(options =>
        {
            // Cookie settings
            options.Cookie.HttpOnly = true;
            options.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5);
            options.LoginPath = "/Account/Signin";
            options.LogoutPath = "/Account/Signout";
            options.AccessDeniedPath = "/Account/AccessDenied";
            options.SlidingExpiration = true;
        });

        services.AddScoped(typeof(IAppLogger<>), typeof(LoggerAdapter<>));
        services.AddScoped<IBookCategoryService, BookCategoryService>();
        services.AddScoped<IBookService, BookService>();

        services.AddHttpClient("chikoroapi", c => 
        {
            c.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:5100/api");
        });

        services.Configure<IdentityOptions>(options =>
        {
            // Password settings.
            options.Password.RequireDigit = true;
            options.Password.RequireLowercase = true;
            options.Password.RequireNonAlphanumeric = true;
            options.Password.RequireUppercase = true;
            options.Password.RequiredLength = 8;
            options.Password.RequiredUniqueChars = 1;

            // Lockout settings.
            options.Lockout.DefaultLockoutTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5);
            options.Lockout.MaxFailedAccessAttempts = 3;
            options.Lockout.AllowedForNewUsers = true;

            // User settings.
            options.User.AllowedUserNameCharacters = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789-._@+";
            options.User.RequireUniqueEmail = true;
        });

        services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_2);

        _services = services;
    }
```

And the configure method is as below

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            ListAllRegisteredServices(app);
            app.UseDatabaseErrorPage();
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
            // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
            //app.UseHsts();
        }

        app.UseHttpsRedirection();
        app.UseStaticFiles();
        app.UseCookiePolicy();
        app.UseAuthentication();
        app.UseMvc(routes =>
        {
            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "default",
                template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
        });
    }
```

I have cross-checked with the documentation several times and I can't figure out what I am missing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SignIn persists the given information for future requests, it does not set HttpContext.User on the current one.

You could only get `User.Identity.IsAuthenticated` as ture for subsequent request on login.

Refer to https://github.com/aspnet/Security/issues/1318

Comment: is this still applicable in 2.2? It seems it was meant for 2.0

Comment: There's no different in 2.0 or 2.2.PasswordSignInAsync issues a Cookie that contains the login information, which isn't read until another request is made and the Cookie sent along with it. Try adding [Authorize] to an endpoint and then check the value of User.Identity.IsAuthenticated there

Comment: If I add the Authorize attribute on the controller I am redirecting to I am getting ERR_SPDY_PROTOCOL_ERROR. Sorry to bother you, do you have any good tutorials you can recommend with regards to ASP.NET Identiy. I am coming from MVC5 so I need to migrate my apps to ASP.NET Core.

Comment: Have you read asp.net core [identity doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/identity?view=aspnetcore-2.2&tabs=visual-studio) of authentication and authorization?